# Rest-assured. Is it possible to extract JSONObject/JSONArray from response json?

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, jsonpath

I'm Using RestAssured,
and i'm getting the response like this-

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Sub": {
            "SubDetails": [
                {
                    "OrgId": 5,
                    "SubId": 1,
                    "SubName": "Mathematics"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "RawData": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:11111/cases/case-15",
        "Type": "Rest",
        "Request": {
            "Details": {
                "OrganizationId": 5,
                "Student": {
                    "Age": 30,
                    "Religion": "Hindu",
                    "StudentId": 10
                }
            }
        },
        "Response": {
            "SmartReturnObject": {
                "Subject": [
                    {
                        "SubjectId": 1,
                        "SubjectName": "Mathematics"
                    }
                ],
                "OrganizationId": 5
            }
        },
        "IsApiError": false
    },
    "SessionId": "5q0",
    "RequestUniqueId": "4543534",
    "StatusCode": "4540000",
    "StatusMessage": "Success",
    "DataSource": "DD"
}
```

Now i need to extract the **Data** object separate and **RawData** separate but i'm failed.
I tried with JSONPath also but not getting it in JSON format.
**I tried**

```
JsonPath body= response.jsonPath();
          Object value=body.get("Data");
          System.out.println("Value is-"+value);
```

and getting it like this - `{Sub={SubDetails=[{OrgId=5, SubId=1, SubName=Mathematics}]}}`
I want the response as **instanceof JSONObject** or **JSONArray** type.

Answer (score 0):

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Try below -

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try {
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(givenString));
}catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank  you for your response @Vishnu but still my condition is getting failed.

Comment: I'm checking the result as ``if (value instanceof JSONObject) `` and ``value instanceof JSONArray`` but it's failed in both condition. I want the result value in these formats.

Comment: Getting this ``The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined``

Comment: what java version you are using?

Comment: I'm using JAVA 8.

Comment: In my Json response their are ``instanceof JSONObject`` and ``instanceof JSONArray`` both present, how to do that